# How to write a obfuscater for javascript code?

Tags: javascript, parsing, obfuscation, google-closure-compiler

I want to write a program that scans javascript code, and replace variable names with short, meaningless identifiers, without breaking the code.

I know YUI compresser and google's closure compiler can do this. I am wondering how can I implement this?

Is it necessary to build the abstract syntax tree? If not, how can I find the candidate variables for renaming?

Comment: `minify` the javascript file

Comment: Minification (like JSMin) is about removing extra spaces, comments, etc, different from obfuscation.

Comment: [Uglify2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) is a well known uglifier/obfuscater for JavaScript code. If you look at the creator's personal website's [page on Uglify](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/), you can see that Uglify does in fact use an AST to compress and mangle code.

Comment: Why do you want to implement this yourself?

Comment: A pet project, to see how it is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most modern javascript compressors are actually compilers. They parse javascript input into an abstract syntax tree, perform operations on the tree (some safe, some not) and then use the syntax tree to print out code. Both Uglify and Closure-Compiler are true compilers.

Implementing your own compiler is a large project and requires a great knowledge of computing theory. The [dragon book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811) is a great resource from which to get started.

You may be able to leverage existing work. I recommend starting from a [non-optimizing compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I made http://www.whak.ca for **whacking scripts** to unreadable obfuscation, over **75 algorithms** ready for you to obfuscate your code. There are also **20 compression** JavaScript packers on http://www.whak.ca/packer/ that will obfuscate your codes. These all can be reversed engineered if someone wanted your code bad enough. But people can pick locks, yet we still lock our doors...

Comment: The randomizing ofuscators on first link will be different everytime you use them...